# How to multiply different numbers from different lines in a text

Tags: python, loops

I have a text file like this:

```
month /name/ number/ price
1 John 100 120.00
1 Sean 90 125.00
1 Laura 150 100.00
1 Joseph 95 140.00
1 Pam 91 105.00
2 John 110 120.00
2 Sean 98 100.00
2 Laura 100 100.00
2 Joseph 89 150.00
2 Pam 100 100.00
3 John 100 121.00
3 Sean 90 120.00
3 Laura 97 100.00
3 Joseph 120 110.00
3 Pam 101 100.00
```

I need to get a specific person's (such as Pam) revenue per month and total revenue in 1,2 and 3 months (number*price). I have the code below and the output below. But I have no idea how to get the total revenue, can anyone give to me some advice or idea?

```
#This is the code I use
f = input('Enter The File Name:')
sales_data = open("sales.txt",'r')
lines = sales_data.readlines()
m = input('Enter the Manager Name:')
print('Monthly Sales Report for' +'  ' + m)
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    tr = (float(line[2]) * float(line[3]))    
    if m in line:
        print(line[0] +'  ' + line[2] + '  ' + line[3] +'  ' + str(tr))
```

```
#This is the output I got

Enter the Manager Name: Pam
Monthly Sales Report for  Pam
1  91  105.00  9555.0
2  100  100.00  10000.0
3  101  100.00  10100.0
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase "I need to get a specific person's (such as Pam) revenue per month and total revenue in 1,2 and 3 months (number*price)." ? You could have multiple lines for Pam in a month and you want to sum them together and output them per month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve your issue is to store all monthly values in a dictionary for a particular manager:

```
file_name = input('Enter The File Name: ')

manager_summary = {'1':0.0, '2':0.0, '3':0.0}

with open (file_name, 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    manager = input('Enter the Manager Name: ')
    print('Monthly Sales Report for' +'  ' + manager)
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        if manager in line:
            manager_summary[line[0]] += float(line[-2])*float(line[-1])

manager_total = 0.0
for key, value in manager_summary.items():
    manager_total += value
print(manager_total)
```

The code reads the input file at once, loops through all the lines in search of the target manager and stores cumulative monthly sales for that manager in a dictionary. The total revenue for 3 month period is then computed by adding cumulative values for each month stored in the dictionary.

There were couple changes with respect to your original code worth noting:

- In your code you ask the user for a file name but then you have it hardcoded in the next line - here you use that input file name.
- Instead of opening the file with `open` this code uses `with open` - with open is a context manager that will automatically close the file for your when closing is needed, something that your were missing in your program.
- Cumulative data is stored in a dictionary with keys being month numbers. This allows for having more than one monthly entry per manager.
- Variable names are more meaningful. It is generally not recommended to use variables like `f`, `m`, it makes the program more bug prone and way less readable. The ones used here are longish, you can always come up with something inbetween.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and thanks for your advice on my codes :) I'm new to python and still learn how to use the dictionary.

Comment: Gladly. `with open` and dictionaries are very useful. As for the style notes, it was my past speaking ;) many of us start with those one letter variables (I think..) etc. - just to learn that the code is unreadable 3 months later :D

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a dictionary - specifically a `defaultdict`.  You can keep track of a dictionary of people's names to revenue.

First import `defaultdict` and define a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
revenue_dictionary = defaultdict(float)
```

Then just after you've calculated `tr`, add this to the dictionary:

```
revenue_dictionary[line[1]] += tr
```

At the end of the script, you'll have a dictionary which looks like:

```
{
    'John': 37300.0,
    'Sean': 31850.0,
    'Laura': 34700.0,
    'Joseph': 39850.0,
    'Pam': 29655.0
}
```

And you can access any of these using `revenue_dictionary['Pam']`, or `m` instead of `'Pam'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = input('Enter The File Name: ')
sales_data = open(f,'r')
lines = sales_data.readlines()
m = input('Enter the Manager Name: ')
print('Monthly Sales Report for ' + m)
TOTAL_REVENUE=0
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    if m in line:
        tr = (float(line[2]) * float(line[3]))
        TOTAL_REVENUE=TOTAL_REVENUE+tr
        print(line[0] +'  ' + line[2] + '  ' + line[3] +'  ' + str(tr))
print("GRAND TOTAL REVENUE: " + str(TOTAL_REVENUE))
```